# Properly defining an ability in CanCan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I'm using CanCan for authorization. The code below is working the way I intend for users, i.e. it allows non-admin users to view their own pages but not those of other users. However, the line defining the Gradebook ability allows access both to the user's gradebook (it's a has-one relationship with gradebook belonging to the user) as well as being able to view other users' gradebooks.

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.has_role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    else
      can :read, User, :id => user.id
      can :read, Gradebook, :user_id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

The CanCan documentation includes this example:

```
can :read, Project, :active => true, :user_id => user.id
```

which seems to offer a model for what I'm trying to do, but I can't get CanCan to prevent access to other users' gradebooks while allowing access to the user's own. 
I've tried the following as well:

```
cannot :read, Gradebook do |book|
  book.user_id != user.id
end
```

but this prevents access to any gradebook. I've also tried a myriad of other permutations to no avail.

Comment: How are you loading Gradebook in your controller? If you use Cancan's load_and_authorize_resource it should handle it correctly.

Comment: OK. I just figured this one out myself. I'll explain the answer in case it'll help anyone else.

Comment: Please edit your answer out of your question, and add it as an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. It has to do with the fact that Gradebook is a nested resource. In the Gradebook controller, I originally just had put the load_and_authorize_resource call, but I changed it to:

```
load_and_authorize_resource :user
load_and_authorize_resource :gradebook, :through => :user, :singleton => true
```

Then in my ability file I used this:

```
  can :read, Gradebook, :user => { :id => user.id }
```

and now it behaves as desired.

Answer (score 0):

I have codes like this in my apps, and it works well. You may have a try:

```
def initialize(user)
  user ||= User.new
  if user.has_role? :admin
    can :manage, :all
  else
    can :read, user
    can :read, Gradebook, user: user
  end
end
```